# how to understand mongoDB Api method requirements?

Tags: mongodb

i was following along a youtube tutorial video for mongoDB.

the method used was deleteMany from the collection class

and the code was:

```
function deleteManyItems(MyMongoClient){

var mydb = MyMongoClient.db('school');
var myColl = mydb.collection('students');

myColl.deleteMany(function(error, result){
    if(error){
        console.log('Sorry unable to delete items');
    }else{
        console.log(result);

    }

})
```

Although the above code worked,iam a bit confused becasue the official docs for the method say there should be a "filter". And my code worked without the filter:

deleteMany(filter, options, callback)
Delete multiple documents from a collection
lib/collection.js, line 945

My question is how do you know when reading the API documentations what is compulsory and what is not, as it doesn't say in the documentation. is it something you have to figure out by experimenting?

Comment: MongoDB docs are very good. What's the environment you're in, node js and some library?

Comment: iam using vs code, nodejs and mongoDB
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#deleteMany

Comment: what happens when u run it? Removes anything?

Answer (score 0):

The docs should say which parameters are required. You shouldn't need to guess.

But, they don't as far as I can tell.

Thus, you have to figure out the proper usage the hard way (trial and error or referencing other resources).

Note that in JavaScript, in general:

- The language syntax permits invoking any function with any number of parameters. Therefore, in the example you gave, the following invocations would be allowed by the language:

```
deleteMany()
deleteMany(filter)
deleteMany(filter, options)
deleteMany(filter, options, callback)
deleteMany(filter, options, callback, ignoredParameter)
```

- Despite the *language* allowing all those invocations, the *implementation of the particular method* may not. For example, providing 4 parameters like the last example may work the same as providing 3 parameters or it might fail with various errors.
- The callback is often the last parameter.
- Parameters named `options` can often be omitted.
- If a method accepts a callback, the callback is often allowed to be the last parameter even when it technically violates the documented invocation, for example:

```
deleteMany(filter, callback)
```

These conventions don't have to be obeyed by any particular library, therefore they *should* be documented in the documentation attached to the library.

The [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#deleteMany) for deleteMany states that `options` is optional but does not state that `filter` is optional. Therefore, it appears to incorrectly claim that `filter` is required whereas it really isn't.

Comment: thanks for the advice. It's hard to learn and practice programming on your own especially with poor documentations